# Flutter: HitTestBehavior.translucent giving wrong and inconsistent results?

Tags: flutter, dart

I thought that `translucent` behavior means that If we had children A and B in a stack (in this order, i.e. A is behind B visually), then tapping a common area between A and B will invoke the tap handlers on both widgets, but upon experiments with the code, I found that this is not the actual behavior, and that the actual behavior is even inconsistent and weird.

To be more clear, I expect:

- when B is translucent, then tapping on B should also pass the tap to A and invoke A's tap handlers.
- when B is opaque, then tapping B only invokes tap handlers on B.
- when B is deferToChild, then B's child decides the tap-handling mechanism when B is tapped.

But anyway, if you look at the logs below, you will see that even when the behavior is explicitly set to translucent, the taps sometimes pass to the child behind and sometimes not, even though I was tapping in the same exact location.

I wrote this minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (_) {
          print('outer gd tapped');
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTapDown: (_) {
              print('inner gd tapped');
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.cyanAccent,
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is an image of the app:

[image]

Here are the logs after tapping the cyan container mutliple times rapidly (you can see how sometimes `outer gd tapped` is printed which means the taps pass to the widget behind the top widget which is the cyan container, now this is what I mean by inconsistent behavior, I was tapping in the same spot when all these logs were generated):

```
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: outer gd tapped    <---------- see this one
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: outer gd tapped    <---------- see this one
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: outer gd tapped    <---------- see this one
flutter: inner gd tapped
flutter: outer gd tapped    <---------- see this one
flutter: inner gd tapped
```

Comment: So here A is red and B is cyanAccent?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes